# Waiting for FB openActiveSession to complete?

Tags: ios, facebook

Sorry if there is a hidden answer but I wasn't able to find it after searching for a while.

I'm currently trying to use Facebook's SDK to create and open an active session and in my method I start with this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"]     
                    allowLoginUI:NO 
                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {}];
```

However, I want to make sure that the session actually changes to FBSessionStateOpen (right now it remains as FBSessionStateCreateOpen) but the rest of my code gets executed before the session changes.

How can I ensure that the login process completes and updates the active session before I move onto to the rest of my function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to use the FBLoginView delegation methods to check when it finished getting the user's information from Facebook.

This is what I needed:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:user:
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the rest of your function inside the completionHandler.

Eg:

```
completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if (FB_ISSESSIONSTATEOPEN(status)) {
        // your code..
    }
}
```